# Set maximum default value for a Django model FloatField

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How can I set the maximum value an `FloatField` can hold in a Django model?

```
price_upper_bound = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
```

Here I want to set maximum float value as a default value for this field. I can set it up manually as any random maximum like `2147483647` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html). Is there any default maximum constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you the max float in python:

```
import sys
sys.float_info.max
```

More info:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.float_info
Out[2]: sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```